# .htaccess special characters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

I want to change characters in url. For example from this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/palety-ciężkie
```

to this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/palety-ciezkie
```

I want to change signs:

```
ą|a, Ą|a, ć|c, Ć|c, ę|e, Ę|e, ł|l, Ł|l, ń|n, Ń|n, ó|o, Ó|o, ś|s, Ś|s, ź|z, Ź|z, ż|z, Ż|z
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that although the URI `/abc-ą` gets encoded as `/abc-%C4%85`, it gets unencoded when sent through the rewrite engine. So you'd need a rule for converting each one of those:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)ą(.*)$ /$1a$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ą(.*)$ /$1a$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ć(.*)$ /$1c$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ć(.*)$ /$1c$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ę(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Ę(.*)$ /$1e$2 [R=301,L]
```

Etc. If you don't want to redirect and instead want the URI rewritten internally on the server (e.g. make it so the browser's address bar doesn't change), then remove the `R=301.` from the brackets.

Another option is to create a map file and use [mod_rewrite's RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), but you'd need access to either server or vhost config in order to set that up.

Comment: It's not working. I'd try every option with R=301, and without it, even try to replace e.g. %C5%9 to s. Still not working